# Entity Framework Code first is padding out strings inserted to a char field

Tags: postgresql, .net-core, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I'm using Entity Framework to add test data to an integration database. I then read this out directly with NpgSql (easier to write PostGis queries direct in text).

One of the string properties of my entity model maps to a column that has a datatype of `char(255)`. Entity Framework is padding this out so that my production code reads out all of the spaces which fails my tests.

Is there anyway to disable or circumvent this padding - its not like the field won't take a shorter value than 255. I don't want to modify my production code to handle this problem with my test suite

Comment: that is how char(n) works - the padding is sql standard.

Comment: @topsail, how come I am able to insert directly a short string into that column either with through datagrip of the .net but running my insert directly with NpgSql

Comment: I'm not following the meaning of your last comment. I think you have not clearly described your error/problem here - can you provide more details. To my mind, you are saying you are reading spaces when running tests (which you think is wrong) but maybe the tests are wrong -- testing for varchar(n) behavior with char(n) data.

Comment: Ok, so I can write the following INSERT INTO Table (column) VALUES ('Test') And when i query that I get back test. When I create an entry with EF Core with the column set to "Text", when I SELECT column FROM Table I get "Test           " etc.. There must be a way to force EF Core to insert exactly what I specified.

Comment: I'm still not sure I follow. If you create a database with a char(10) column and insert `Test` into that column, the value stored is `Test      `. This is literally how databases work. Its seems like you want (or expect) that this column behave like a varchar() column. But you have to deal with what you actually have.

Comment: Consider using the `text` PG data type instead of char(10), or possibly varchar(10) if you want a size limit. Avoid char(x) in general.